# Auth facade returns null if called from Controller with api route

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, model-view-controller

I am accessing a `PayPalController` through routes in `routes/api.php` but when I try to check if a user is authenticated, it returns `null`.

**`PayPalController`**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Srmklive\PayPal\Service\Paypal;

class PayPalController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Request $request)
    {

        // returns null
        $id = Auth::id();

        // can't read "id" of null
        $id = auth('api')->user()->id;
        
    }
}
```

**`routes/api.php`**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


Route::post('/paypal/order/create', [PayPalController::class, 'create']);
```

I've tried creating an `api guard` in `config/auth.php` and using it like so:

```
auth('api')->user()->id
```

but it changes nothing.

**Edit**:

A user is authenticated and it still returns null.

Comment: If you want to check if a user is authenticated, why you are not using `auth()->check()` or `Auth::check()` instead?

Comment: Auth::id() returns null because no user is authenticated yet.

Comment: Finally, just use `auth()->user()->id` instead of `auth('api)`

Comment: API routes are STATELESS.  If you want a session authenticated user, move the route to web.php

Comment: A user is authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

It returns null, because no user is authenticated yet. If you want to check for user authentication, you can just use it like:

```
If(Auth::check()){
    //Your code here
}
```

Or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can be define middleware in the constructer of your controller

```js
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:api');
}
```

Comment: I've tried that but nothing happens. The route does not seem to be reached. Not even an error message in log.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your route will be add on middleware.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'] ,function () {

    Route::post('/paypal/order/create', [PayPalController::class, 'create']);

});
```

Auth will be check this is login ya not and pass your login. If you check your api then pass the bearer token then run the api and access your `$id = Auth::id();` auth id.

Comment: I've tried that but nothing happens. The route does not seem to be reached. Not even an error message in log.

Comment: bearer token pass on your postman headers.without token you can not access this api.